# How to delete an s3 object tag for some versions using java sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I trying to delete s3 tags for some versions of an s3 object. I have the s3 object versions list.

I am able to delete tags using bucket and key alone using the below code.

```
final AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(clientRegion)
                .build();

s3Client.deleteObjectTagging(new DeleteObjectTaggingRequest(bucket, key));
```

Kindly help me with deleting s3 tag for a specified version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/DeleteObjectTaggingRequest.html).

The `DeleteObjectTaggingRequest` constructor only requests about bucket name and object key but you can select the version by `withVersionId(String versionId)`. So,

```
DeleteObjectTaggingRequest req = new DeleteObjectTaggingRequest(bucket, key).withVersionId(version)
```

would work.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 'versionId' to your request, with the Objects' version Id. 
If you wish to remove tags from several versions, then I think a loop would work best.

---

For more info check this out:

---

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObjectTagging.html

Cheers.

Comment: I have already tried adding version id to my request like this. s3Client.deleteObjectTagging(new DeleteObjectTaggingRequest(bucket, key, versionid)); It didnt accept 3rd versionid parameter.  This is the s3 sdk version i am using. <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.656</version>

Comment: Okay, how about you try  _"new DeleteObjectsRequest(bucket_name)
            .withKeys(object_keys)"_ ?
Edit: You can find an example here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#delete-object

Comment: I am trying to delete the tag, not object!